# Select a tab in Internet Explorer

Tags: vba, shell, internet-explorer, ui-automation

I am using a combination of shell.application to find my relevant Internet explorer and using UIAutomation to then work on popup that comes for the file download I give on the given page.  This worked great till the time I had a single Internet explorer.  Now I have to do the same from four different tabs of Internet explorer.

Shell.application part of the program works great.  But for UIAutomation to work the given web page needs to be the in front of the screen.  I want to see if this can be achieved using shell.application or I am open to suggestions.

Note I did a lot of search but was not able to find the right content.  I have pasted both the codes.

```
'Connect with ApplicationName
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
    On Error Resume Next    ' sometimes more web pages are counted than are open
    my_url = objShell.Windows(x).document.Location
    my_title = objShell.Windows(x).document.Title

    If my_title Like "ApplicationName" & "*" Then
        Set ie = objShell.Windows(x)
        'ie.<<want some kind of select option >>
        Exit For
    Else
    End If
Next


'Save download - this code does not work unless the Internet explorer is in the front
Application.Wait Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
Dim o As IUIAutomation
Dim e As IUIAutomationElement
Set o = New CUIAutomation
Dim h As Long
h = ie.Hwnd
h = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)
If h = 0 Then Exit Sub

Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal h)
Dim iCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Save")

Dim Button As IUIAutomationElement
Set Button = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd)
Dim InvokePattern As IUIAutomationInvokePattern
Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
InvokePattern.Invoke
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer per se, just better formatting than comment.  I used the below to extract the tab im using for SO.

```
Sub IEs()

Dim x As ShellWindows
Dim i As Integer
Dim w As WebBrowser

Set x = New ShellWindows

For Each w In x
    If w.LocationURL = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40846141/select-a-tab-in-internet-explorer" Then Exit For
Next w

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think I might have found a solution.  Open all the tabs in separate instance of IE and then just make use  ie.visible = false and again use ie.visible = true.  Have to test it out.

Comment: This way the IE I want in front comes up... Have to try and see if this works

Answer (score 0):

I continued to do my research and posting a solution here I found a simple solution.

All that we have to do is instead of opening different web pages as tabs in the same instance of IE we open separate instances of IE and then to bring the relevant web page to the front after we have found it using shell.application is the below two lines.

```
ie.Visible = False
ie.Visible = True
```